# How do I put results for an expression into an array?

Tags: arrays, vbscript

I am using VBScript to find a quarterbacks passer rating. This rating is based on a single season. I would like to find a QBs overall career passer rating by:

1. Running the program to get the single season passer rating program
   to record the result from the given input.
2. Running the program again based on a subsequent or previous season's
       stats
3. Take the collective passer ratings and find the average of all
       seasons

My logic is that I would place each seasons passer rating into an array.

```
dim array()
arrPasserRating = array(Passer1,Passer2, ....)
```

This array would have no upper limit so I assume I would have to do something like this:

```
ReDim Preserve ArrPasserRating(UBound(yourArray) + 1)
arrPasserRating(UBound(arrPasserRating) = "..."
```

where "..." is the next passer rating I calculated.

Now I would have the problem of a naming scheme and creating a for ... next in order to create a new array value with the name of the previous item in the array and adding the "number of the index that it occupies in the array.

For instance passerRating would stay passerRating, the next inputted passerRating would be passerRating1, etc.

Does anyone have a starting point for me or a solution to this problem?

Comment: I don't understand your aim. Pay your attention to `Dim` and `ReDim` statements and to `Array()`  function in [VBScript Language Reference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d1wf56tt(v=vs.84).aspx).

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand your question correctly. Are you trying to build a list of numbered labels with a common prefix? If so: why? Labels usually don't have a meaning in and by themselves. If you want the labels mapped to something else, I strongly suspect that a different data structure might be better suited for whatever problem you're trying to solve here.

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers Sounds to me like they are trying to build a list of variables dynamically based on calculated values taken from an array. You need to look at `Eval()` and `Execute()` in the VBScript Scripting Reference. `Execute()` should provide what you require.

Comment: @Lankymart A dictionary would be a better solution for that.

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers Out of interest why?, don't find `Scripting.Dictionary` too efficient.

Comment: @Lankymart Because there are *way* too many ways to mess up with `Eval` et. al. Dictionaries are a much safer approach if all you need are dynamic variable names.

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers Can't say I've ever had any dire issues using `Eval()` or `Execute()` but point taken.

Comment: I want to be able to take the results of an executed expression and save them into an array. Then at the users choosing, they can find the average numerical value of all the elements in an array. Each result from the program needs to be placed in an array before the program repeats it self upon user request.