# Can I instantiate an object or class with a random variable?

Tags: object, vbscript

Let's say that I have an object...

```
Class test
    Public a
    Public b
End class
```

And in my code I would like to instantiate it without knowing a predetermined variable name to store the new instance.

Is this possible? How would I then dim the random variable?

I want to be able to do this because I don't want my user input to be stored or saved in the same variable with other data conflict. Like say for example I am storing stats for an athlete and I ask the athlete's name. If every time the user enters a different name, I don't want to have this information in the same object instance. Could I create an object for the athlete and reference this object inside another object?

I have a snippet of code:

```
Function addStats
    dim pAtt, pComp, pInt, pTds, pYds, endNum, pName
    Wscript.StdOut.WriteLine "What is your quarterback's name"
    pName = Wscript.StdIn.ReadLine

    Wscript.StdOut.WriteLine "How many attempts: "
    pAtt = Wscript.StdIn.ReadLine
    'chkNum(pAtt)
    Wscript.StdOut.WriteLine "How many completions: "
    pComp = Wscript.StdIn.ReadLine
    'chkNum(pComp)
    Wscript.StdOut.WriteLine "How many yards: "
    pYds = Wscript.StdIn.ReadLine
    'chkNum = pYds
    Wscript.StdOut.WriteLine "How many touchdowns: "
    pTds = Wscript.StdIn.ReadLine
    'chkNum = pTds
    Wscript.StdOut.WriteLine "How many interceptions: "
    pInt = Wscript.StdIn.ReadLine
    'chkNum = pInt
    endNum = UBound(newStats) + 1
    redim preserve newStats(endNum)

    '---- vvvv ----
    set newStats(endNum) = new QB
    '---- ^^^^ ----

    newStats(endNum).att = pAtt
    newStats(endNum).comp = pComp
    newStats(endNum).yds = pYds
    newStats(endNum).tds = pTds
    newStats(endNum).ints = pInt
    newStats(endNum).qbname = pName
    Wscript.StdOut.WriteLine "Stats Added"
    writeBuffer()
end Function
```

The object is:

```
class QB
    dim att, comp, yds, tds, ints, qbname

    public property let qbAtt(n)
        att = n
    end property
    public property let qbComp(n)
        comp = n
    end property
    public property let qbYds(n)
        yds = n
    end property
    public property let qbTds(n)
        tds = n
    end property 
    public property let qbInt(n)
        ints = n
    end property
    public property let qName(n)
        qbname = n
    end property

    public property get qbAtt
        qbAtt = att
    end property
    public property get qbComp 
        qbComp = comp
    end property
    public property get qbYds
        qbYds = yds
    end property
    public property get qbTds
        qbTds = tds
    end property
    public property get qbInt
        qbInt = ints
    end property
    public property get qName   
        qName = qbname
    end property
end class
```

The highlighted statement is me instantiating the object with a global variable - `newStat()`. My belief is that I would have to either create a class for just the quarterback and somehow reference this into a variable array that is determined on the quarterback's name or create a function that takes the user prompt variable that asks the quarterback's name and set it as an array that instantiates the `QB` class.

Comment: You are talking about "other data conflict", could you please illustrate the case with any code snippet?

Comment: Use a collection / array you store the quarter back instances that way the same variable can be used to initially instantiate them.

Answer (score 1):

I think you're confusing classes, objects, and variables. Classes are basically templates that describe which properties and behavior entities of a particular category have. Objects are instances of a class. Variables are identifiers that refer to objects (or data of primitive types).

Take lockers for example. Lockers usually have a color, they can be opened and closed, and they may contain a number of items. Thus a general description of lockers (a class "Locker") might look like this:

```
Class Locker
  Public color
  Public closed
  Public content

  Sub Class_Initialize
    closed = True
    content = Array()
  End Sub

  Sub Open
    closed = False
  End Sub

  Sub Close
    closed = True
  End Sub
End Class
```

The constructor (`Class_Initialize`) is a special method that is only called when an object (an instance of a class) is created. It sets the initial state of the object. Kind of like when a locker is built in the factory.

A particular locker (object) might be green and contain a hat and a magazine, while another locker (object) might be blue and contain a book and a jacket.

```
Set locker_A = New Locker
locker_A.color = "green"
locker_A.content = Array("hat", "magazine")

Set locker_B = New Locker
locker_B.color = "blue"
locker_B.content = Array("book", "jacket")
```

To be able to actually work with objects (or other data) in a program you need variables. These identifiers (`locker_A` and `locker_B` in the example above) allow you to refer to particular objects in your program code in order to access their properties and methods.

When you run a statement

```
Set newStats(2) = New QB
```

it creates a new instance of the class `QB` (a new object) and places a reference to that object in the third slot of the array `newStats`. Afterwards you can use `newStats(2)` to refer to that object in your program or script. For instance:

```
newStats(2).yds = 42 'yards
```

If you have a number of `QB` object and store each of them in a different array slot there shouldn't be any conflict between them, as long as you don't replace a reference in one slot with another one.

```
Set newStats(2) = newStats(5)  '<-- don't do this
```

If you wanted to access objects from the list by a particular property (for instance the name) instead of by index you'd use a [`Dictionary`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x4k5wbx4%28v=vs.84%29) instead of an array:

```
Set newStats = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
newStats.CompareMode = vbTextCompare    'make lookups case-insensitive

...

Set player = New QB
player.att = pAtt
...
player.qbname = pName

newStats.Add pName, player
```

Then you could access a particular player like this:

```
name = "Charley Johnson"
WScript.Echo newStats(name).yds
```

Comment: Thanks for the clarification! How can I code this to allow for data manipulation. Say for instance, I have a quarterbackA and a quarterbackB. quarterbackA has two game entries and quarterbackB has one entry. If I didn't know the index of the array they were both in but wanted to only compare and work with the data that belongs to quarterbackA, how would I go about this? Would I have to do a for each statement with an if statement nested inside of it to compare the array with the quarterback in  question? Thanks for any advice!

Comment: Use a dictionary. I already told you that in response to a [previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/33336842/1630171) of yours. Please pay attention.

Comment: Thanks. Will try that.